# How to create a config file for kube-scheduler to use by the --config argument

Tags: kubernetes

As kubernetes 1.9 , all flags than --config are deprecated on kube-scheduler. So how to create config file ?

Comment: See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/58805 for the same issue, in the Kubernetes official bug tracker.

Comment: Have you had any success finding an example config file? https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/62515 looks like `--write-config-to` won't be available until 1.11.

Answer (score 4):

Building from tip and using `--write-config-to` yields a sample config file. Examining it, it's a yaml file using [KubeSchedulerConfig](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/apis/componentconfig#KubeSchedulerConfiguration) as the schema.

Sample config (no other flags specified):

```
algorithmSource:
  provider: DefaultProvider
apiVersion: componentconfig/v1alpha1
clientConnection:
  acceptContentTypes: ""
  burst: 100
  contentType: application/vnd.kubernetes.protobuf
  kubeconfig: ""
  qps: 50
disablePreemption: false
enableContentionProfiling: false
enableProfiling: false
failureDomains: kubernetes.io/hostname,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region
hardPodAffinitySymmetricWeight: 1
healthzBindAddress: 0.0.0.0:10251
kind: KubeSchedulerConfiguration
leaderElection:
  leaderElect: true
  leaseDuration: 15s
  lockObjectName: kube-scheduler
  lockObjectNamespace: kube-system
  renewDeadline: 10s
  resourceLock: endpoints
  retryPeriod: 2s
metricsBindAddress: 0.0.0.0:10251
schedulerName: default-scheduler
```